# Pandas: How to construct a table with column and row keys from numerical ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use pandas dataframes to create a two-dimensional table. The table should associate two values `alpha` and `epsilon` with a third value. `alpha` and `epsilon` come from a variable range, like:

```
alphaRange = numpy.arange(0.01, 0.26, 0.01)
epsilonRange = numpy.arange(0.01, 0.11, 0.01)
```

(The goal is to find out which combination of `alpha` and `epsilon` leads to the highest values, or more generally, find a correlation between parameters and values.)

What is the best way to construct such a dataframe and later fill it with values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use NumPy to compute the values first, and then load the result into a DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
alphaRange = np.arange(0.01, 0.26, 0.01)
epsilonRange = np.arange(0.01, 0.11, 0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(alphaRange, epsilonRange)
vals = X+Y
print(vals.shape)
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=epsilonRange, columns=alphaRange)
print(df)
```

Edit: PaulH is right -- floats do not make good column or index labels, since they could be hard to reference properly. (Checking floats for equality brings up float-representation issues.) So it would be better to make `alpha` and `epsilon` DataFrame columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':vals.ravel()},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([alphaRange, epsilonRange],
                                                   names=['alpha', 'epsilon']))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

yields

```
   alpha  epsilon  vals
0   0.01     0.01  0.02
1   0.01     0.02  0.03
2   0.01     0.03  0.04
3   0.01     0.04  0.05
4   0.01     0.05  0.06

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

pd.MultiIndex.from_product was added in pandas 0.13.1. For earlier versions of pandas, you could use:

```
def from_product(iterables, sortorder=None, names=None):
    from pandas.tools.util import cartesian_product
    product = cartesian_product(iterables)
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(product, sortorder=sortorder,
                                  names=names)

df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':vals.ravel()},
                  index=from_product([alphaRange, epsilonRange],
                                     names=['alpha', 'epsilon']))
```

Comment: are float indices still unstable/frowned upon?

Comment: @PaulH: Thanks, Paul. I think you are right; float indices may be problematic. I've posted an alternative.

Comment: @unutbu I don't quite understand the `vals = X+Y` line in your example. `alphaRange` and `epsilonRange` are used for indexing, the values are not a simple combination (e.g. sum) of the two. So to write the values, I need to be able to index the array by `(alpha, epsilon)`.

Comment: `alpha` and `epsilon` are floats. You need ints, bools or slices to index an array. Can you give an example of how the vals are calculated?

Comment: @unutbu Assume that they are the result of a complex calculation. I just need a way to get the correct indices that correspond to `alpha` and `epsilon`. Currently trying `numpy.where(alphaRange == alpha)`.

Comment: Also, I get an error on `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`: `AttributeError: type object 'MultiIndex' has no attribute 'from_product'` The method does not seem to exist.

Comment: `MultiIndex.from_product` was a relatively new addition to pandas. It can be rewritten without it... probably using `itertools.product`. The bigger problem is the way you are doing the complex calculation. Calling `numpy.where(alphaRange == alpha)` once for every value of `alpha` is inefficient. It suggests that you are looping through all `alpha`, `epsilon` pairs. This is usually not the right way to take advantage of NumPy. It leads to disappointingly slow code. Instead, you want to perform calculations on whole arrays, not using Python loops to calculate individual values one at a time.

Comment: You can loop through the (alpha, epsilon) indices using `for i, j in np.ndindex((len(alphaRange),len(epsilonRange)))`, and then do the calculation cell-by-cell, but this is likely to be slow way to perform the calculation and should only be done if finding the value at `(0,0)` is required *before* finding the value at `(0,1)`, etc.